# Get next month from current date in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a p tag with the next month, for example now is December But the p tag should be display January, If we in Jan the p tag should be display Febrary. What I have until now is this.

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const d = new Date();
let name = month[d.getMonth()];
document.getElementById("currentmonth").innerHTML = name;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="currentmonth"></p>
<p id="nextmonth"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? The logic is fairly simple. Add one unless it is currently December when you go back to zero

Comment: Sorry I'm Nov in Javascript.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take a variable and add one to the `getMonth()` value and if it is greater than 11 then change it to 0.

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const d = new Date();
let name = month[d.getMonth()];
var x = d.getMonth()+1;
if(x>11)
  x=0
  
document.getElementById("currentmonth").innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById("nextmonth").innerHTML = month[x];
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="currentmonth"></p>
<p id="nextmonth"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use setMonth to set the next month on the d variable.

```
d.setMonth(Month + 1)
```

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

    let Month = 11 
   const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(Month + 1)
let name = month[d.getMonth()];
document.getElementById("currentmonth").innerHTML = name;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="currentmonth"></p>
<p id="nextmonth"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the months is according to the real month indexes, you can do it as follows.

and i guess you forgot set value `nextMonth`

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const d = new Date();
let name = month[d.getMonth()];
let next = month[(new Date().getMonth()+1)%12];
document.getElementById("currentmonth").innerHTML = `Current: ${name}`;
document.getElementById("nextmonth").innerHTML = `Next: ${next}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="currentmonth"></p>
<p id="nextmonth"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @StephanBauer thx i didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const d = new Date();
let name = month[d.getMonth()];
let nextMonth = month[(d.getMonth() + 1)%12]
document.getElementById("currentmonth").innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById("nextmonth").innerHTML = nextMonth;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="currentmonth"></p>
<p id="nextmonth"></p>

</body>
</html>
```